# Locks and commit failures

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

Here is the scenario. I lock a row in a read write transaction and then commit the transaction. If the commit is successful, that will release the lock as well. What if the commit is failed for some reason? Should I explicitly Rollback the transaction to release the locks or the commit failure would automatically release any locks. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locks are released on failure. You only need to call rollback if you don't issue the session.commit request.